# .htaccess PHP rewrite link

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I have problem and dont have any idea how to solve it.
I have URL like this:
http://somedomain.com/link.php?lnk=1&sid=dsds

and need to change it to this:

http://somedomain.com/link/1/dsds

If there is only one variable I use this:

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^link/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ link.php?lnk=$1`

But I don't have any idea how to attach that second variable &sid={something}

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you checked out any of the many many duplicates? -->

Comment: Yes and did not found any answer to my problem

Comment: @MichałBereszyński, **RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?p=$1&sp=$2 [L] **

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 RewriteEngine on 
 RewriteRule ^link/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ link.php?lnk=$1&sid=$2
```

Answer (score 1):

if the first parameter/value uses digits only, then you can use

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule ^link/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ link.php?lnk=$1&sid=$2 [L]
```

[Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/intro.html) (see "Figure 1" in "Regex Back-Reference Availability" section)

[RewriteRule Flags](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lnk=(.+)\&sid=(.+)
RewriteRule ^link\.php link/%1/%2/?  [R=301,L]
```